# Create an array from another array using some elements from it, fill zero other elements

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array

```
np.random.seed(42)
x = np.random.rand(3, 3)
```

So

```
array([[0.37454012, 0.95071431, 0.73199394],
       [0.59865848, 0.15601864, 0.15599452],
       [0.05808361, 0.86617615, 0.60111501]])
```

I want to create another elements from this array, using only some elements from x, and fill zero other elements, such as, if I want elements `x[1::2,::2]` I will get an array

```
y = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
             [0.59865848, 0, 0.15599452],
             [0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: `out = np.zeros_like(x); out[1::2, ::2] = x[1::2, ::2]`

Comment: @user3483203 thank you! It works!